# php recursive variable won't change

Tags: php

I have a function like:

```
myfunction($i,$condition = false, $level = 0) {
   do {
      if (... some conditions here)   { myfunction($i, true, ++$level) }
      else { do something here ... }
   while ( ...meet ending condition )
}
```

I don't understand why the $condition turn `true` when i call `myfunction()` recursively and come back to `false` when iterating in first level and `$level` won't turn to `0` after it exits a recursive mode.

`$condition = false, false, true, false, false, true, true, true ...`

`$level = 0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2 ... it shoul also be like = 0,0,1,0,0,1,2,2,2,0 ...` and so on
?

Thank you

P.S : It is the same with arrays ? I declared an array in the function set to null and when exits the recursive mode it's not null anymore :

```
myfunction($i,$condition = false, $level = 0, $array = null) {
       do {
    if($condition) { $array = null }    <--------- I HAVE TO ADD THIS LINE TO MAKE IT NULL WHY ?
          if (... some conditions here)   {$array = Array(someblabla); myfunction($i, true, ++$level, $array) }
          else { do something here ... }
       while ( ...meet ending condition )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to all ... $level+1 did the trick as you said. But i don't know why and where is menitoned in the php`s references .

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: Can someone reply to the P.S in Question ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is the difference between `++$level` and `$level+1`. The former modifies the value of `$level`, so that further references to that variable in the same invocation of `myfunction` see the incremented value. If that's not what you want, write `$level+1` instead.

Comment: Genius ... I never understood that . Thank you very much , you saved my brains becaus I started to get frustrated.

Comment: It's the same way with arrays ? because I added an array to the function and when exits recursive mode ... the $array is not null anymore .. it was declared `myfucntion($i, $condition = false, $array = null, $level = 0)` ? Thank you very much

Comment: I think we'd need to see a bit more of the code to understand exactly what's happening with `$array`. Is there anything else that sets $array? Are there any other calls to `myfunction` that provide that fourth parameter?

Comment: the array is set if it met a condition and then function enters recursive mode with the array set, and when it end the recursivity , the array won't turn back to it's null value . I have describen in my question this (P.S)

Comment: Well, after you set `$array` explicitly, further uses of it in that invocation of `myfunction` -- e.g., in later iterations of that do-while loop -- will see the new value. Every time you call the function, you effectively get new versions of all its local variables (including the function arguments), which evaporate when the function returns. So: you call `myfunction` (call this Call 1). Its `$array` is null. It then sets `$array` to something else, and then calls `myfunction` again (call this Call 2). Its `$array` also starts out null. Then Call 2 returns, and back in Call 1 [... continued]

Comment: [... continuation:] back in Call 1, Call 1's `$array` still has the same (non-null) value it had before Call 2 started. It doesn't get set to `null` just because Call 2 has another variable of the same name with that value.

Answer (score 2):

Each executed function has its own local variables. As the name says, these variables are **local**, not shared between recursive calls.

the ++ operator increments the *local* variable.

Comment: I think what pufos is puzzled by is the fact that after the recursive call has returned, `$level` still has an increased value -- not the fact that separate calls to `myfunction` see different things. But the question isn't perfectly clear, so I may have misunderstood.

Comment: (Note: at the point when I wrote the above comment, yi_H's answer did not mention the fact that "the ++ operator increments the local variable".)

Comment: yepp.. weird that SO doesn't show that the answer was edited.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are doing `++$level` which increments the local copy of `$level` and then passes the new incremented value to the recursive call of the function.

Try changing it to `$level + 1` which just passes value of `$value` plus one to the function but does not change the local copy of the variable, so that if the function returns you still have the old un-incremented value in `$value`.

Comment: Thank you very much , that did the trick . But can you explai why ?

Comment: Ok I understood it clea now ... You are perfecty right and make sense.